# How is $P=p^2 / 3E$ justifiable?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, momentum

How can the following relation be justified,
$$ P = \frac{p^2}{3E} $$
where $P$ is pressure, $p$ is momentum and $E$ is energy?
In what convention is the above relation acceptable?

The source paper can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2264).
The relation is not explicitly mentioned there but in the equations it is evident. Please refer to the 4$^\text{th}$ page for equations of state.
Note that that speed of light $c$ and Planck's constant $h/2\pi$ are both taken as unity (one).

Comment: Where from did you take this relation? How did you come to it? Dimensionally, the pressure is force divided by surface, or equivalently mass divided by (length $\times$ time$^2$), while $\frac {p^2}{E}$ has dimension of mass. So, anyway it's not good.

Comment: @lemon: Sofia is right, the dimensions *don't* work out.

Comment: @0celo7 Good idea to check statements. Well done!

Comment: @Sofia: My first instinct is to look for missing $c$s and $\hbar$s. I don't think it works out.

Comment: In particle physics, one kind of tends to take speed of light as 1. So, may be there is some point there for dimensional analysis. I am giving the source paper for the relation in the answer.

Comment: @0celo7  what is $cs$ and $\hbar s$ ? I like to learn new things, so tell me.

Comment: @Sofia Lol the "s" isn't italic. I meant "speeds of light" and "h bars".

Comment: @0celo7   Aaaa! But $\hbar$(s) hasn't much to do here.

Comment: a trivial remark : when building a speculative relation, the dimension analysis may help but it cannot completely close a door, since it is always possible to introduce the missing units in the unavoidable constant factor.

Comment: Implicite or not, I get some difficulties to retrieve the relation in this page.  Could you expand please ? The cited document 22 is on [arxiv] (http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.8044) ...

Comment: actually this relation exists, in thermodynamics when we talk about stellar matter..I wanted to look at the workaround to get to this equation

Comment: Please give the equation number of where you think this relationship exists.

Comment: see eqn 8 and 9. 
P = (1/3)(p^4 /E') (f/pi^2)dp  ;
E = p^2  E' (f/pi^2)dp..
Thus, P = p^2  E' (f/pi^2)dp   times   p^2/3E'^2  =  E times p^2/3E'^2 ~ p^2/3E

I will look for a proper link, but I think I read it in Reif's Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics. I will find a better source and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $P=p^2/(3E)$ makes no sense (it connects a thermodynamic variables, $P$, to the momentum and energy of a single particle). It is also not dimensionally correct. With $c=1$ momentum $p$ and energy $E$ have the same units, but pressure has units of energy/volume (=energy*momentum$^3$).

The equations in the paper look o.k. Pressure is 
$$
P = \int d^3p\,  p \frac{p}{E} \, f(p)
$$
where $f$ is a dimensionless distribution function. The integral $d^3p$ gives 1/volume, $E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$ is an energy,  $v=p/E$ is a velocity. This means we are integrating over $vp$, which is indeed the standard definition of pressure in kinetic theory.

For energy density
$$
{\cal E} = \int d^3p\, E \, f(p)
$$
which clearly makes sense.

Postscript: Pressure is defined as (in kinetic theory)
$$
\Pi_{ij} = \int d^3p\, p_i \frac{p_j}{E}\, f(p) 
$$
with $\Pi_{ij}=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}P$. Then $P= \frac{1}{3}\int d^3p\, p^2/E\, f(p)$ and now we have a rotationally invariant integrand $d^3p=4\pi p^2dp$.

Comment: am sorry. if the equations in the paper look okay, then how doesn't the eqn make no sense.. You start saying it doesn't make sense, but later you say that they look ok. really can't get clear on you here.

Comment: @MycrofD The equation I complain about is not actually in the paper (at least I don't see it)

Comment: uh, yeah. So, then this can be done, right? 
d3p pp/E = ppdp pp/E

Comment: @MycrofD Not sure what you mean by "this". If you mean the pressure integrand then you have to be more careful, see postscript.

Comment: yeah, that's right. I just let go of the 4pi. you are right.

Comment: Got you. Just one query, can you please cite one source/book where I can find the definition of pressure you provided in postscript? I understand that the relation exists in kinetic theory, but I just can't find it.

Comment: @MycrofD Even undergraduate text books usually contain some kind of argument that pressure can be computed from momentum balance in collisions of atoms with the walls, and derive a formula $P\sim \int p^2dp p_x^2 f(p)$. The more formal result can be found in text books on kinetic theory, for example equ.(5.8) in Landau-Lifshitz "Kinetic Theory"

Answer (score 0):

Using dimensional analysis, and the relations $p=mv$ and $E=mgh$, we can write:
$$[P]=\dfrac{kg^2\cdot m^2\cdot s^{-2}}{kg\cdot m^2\cdot s^{-2}}=kg$$

And kilogrammes are obviously not a unit of pressure, therefore your relation doesn't have the correct dimensions.

Comment: you worked too hard, it were simpler to think that energy has the dimension of $\frac {p^2}{2m}$.

Comment: One should take spped of light being taken as unity into account. And yes, I second @Sofia

Comment: @MycrofD you say "And let us remember that speed of light c  and Planck's constant h/2π  are both taken as unity (one)." Well, people cannot know that you work with certain conventions. So, when you ask for help, it's better to leave aside particular conventions and give the people the full formulas. It's advisable to economize time.

Comment: I am not sure how this relation came up. So I am asking. I forgot to cite the source and mention the convention at the first instant of asking the question, my apologies.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to get the dimensions right with $c=\hbar=1$. However, if you add $G=1$, then you need to multiply your relation by $c^{13/2}\hbar^{-3/2}G^{-3/2}$ to get the right dimensions. And since it's pretty ugly, that makes me wonder if you got the relation right in the first place.